# Where can I find the grammar to the Unified EL 2.2?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, el

I spent all day looking for the formal grammar of the Unified Expression Language 2.2, but the best I could find is [this PDF](https://services.brics.dk/java/courseadmin/SWP/documents/getDocument/expression_language-2_2-mrel-spec.pdf?d=61845) that has the specs, but not in a way i can work or use as a reference card.

It is very depressing, since the first thing that comes to mind when dealing with a new formal language is the grammar (but Oracle seems to have a "crack commando team" devoted on obfuscating content on their sites).

Comment: Silly me skimmed the document, and did not noticed the productions until after I posted the question. Let it linger so other people looking for it can find that.

Comment: The link seems to be no longer accessible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The productions are listed in section 1.19 of the linked PDF file.